# Error in array, Scalar?

Tags: php

Code:

```
$i=0;
    while ($i < $rows) {
        $storage_id     =   mysql_result($giftCards,$i,"id");
        $result[$storage_id]['display_name'] = mysql_result($giftCards,$i,"display_name");
        $result[$storage_id]['image_icon'] = mysql_result($giftCards,$i,"image_icon");
        $result[$storage_id]['currency'] = mysql_result($giftCards,$i,"currency");
        $i++;
    }
    return $result;
```

Causes error:

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/chosen/public_html/classes/giftcards.class.php on line 13
```

On several lines.

Anyone have any idea how to correct this? The only time this has popped up has been with the new VPS I setup. Works fine on other servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared $result as an array.
Put a
`$result = array();` before the loop.

Comment: or simply fixing the scope would probably work. eg 1st line should simply be $result;